# How to make the pentagon always face the ico sphere no matter where I put it?

Tags: parent

[image: screenshot of what I want to do]

So how can I make it so that no matter where I move that pentagon, or ico sphere, the pentagon is facing the sphere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a *Track To Constraint* on the pentagon.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But do you also know how to limit it's distance from the object too? Another constraint?

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot and there's literally a limit distance constraint. Nvm then. Thanks a lot.